# Passing data between 2 models in 1 controller function laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller

I need to get the lecture id in my student table and from then only can i get the lecture's data using that id. The problem is, the $lectureID is null when i try to apply it on the lecture model, but when i check on the console, it does get the data. Thanks in advance.

**Controller**

```
public function getLecture($id)
{   
    $lectureID = student::select('lecture_id_FK')->where('student_id',$id)->first();

    $lectureDATA = lecture::where('lecture_id',$lectureID)->first();

    return $lectureDATA;
}
```

Comment: Calling the `first` method on the Query Builder does not return the selected value, it returns an instance of that Eloquent Model with the specified selected fields. This means that the value passed to the `where` condition should be `$lectureID->lecture_id_FK` (although it seems like that should be selecting `lecture_id` not `lecture_id_FK`, but that depends on your column names setup).

Comment: @Bogdan thanks. that fix the problem~

Comment: This is not the Laravelish. You need to define relationships in your models.

Comment: See [model relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try two ways 
public function getLecture($id)
{   
    ## way 1
    $lectureID = student::where('student_id',$id)->value('lecture_id_FK');
    $lectureDATA = lecture::where('lecture_id',$lectureID)->first();

    ## way 2
    $lectureID = student::where('student_id',$id)->first();
    $lectureDATA = lecture::where('lecture_id',$lectureID->lecture_id_FK)->first();
    return $lectureDATA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before check what inside $lectureID:

```
public function getLecture($id)
{   
    $lectureID = student::select('lecture_id_FK')->where('student_id',$id)->first();
    dd($lectureID);//I believe inside will be object with lecture_id_FK
    //then just
    $lectureDATA = lecture::where('lecture_id',$lectureID->lecture_id_FK)->first();
    return $lectureDATA;
}
```

Recommended way to do it:

In Student model class ( recommend use capital S )

```
class student 
{
     public function lecture(){
         return $this->hasOne('App\lecture','lecture_id_FK','lecture_id');
     }
}
```

then just load studen with lecture like this

```
$student = studend::with('lecture')->find($id);
$lecture = $student->lecture;
```